# The effective synchronized collection for a few producers and one consumer

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

What would be the most effective synchronized collection in .net for few producers (threads) and one consumer? Producing is much faster than consuming. Ordering is required.

Would it be just default `BlockingCollection` on `ConcurrentQueue`?

Comment: If you're producing faster than you're consuming, then eventually your queue is going to overflow.

Answer (score 1):

By default `BlockingCollection` wraps `ConcurrentQueue` when you didn't specify `IProducerConsumerCollection<T>` in its constructor.

So whatever you choose to use is pretty same thing. With `BlockingCollection` you get advantage of `GetConsumingEnumerable` method which is deigned for consumer.

Comment: Will this be fastest then others? with less synchronization overhead

Comment: I can't answer this question you only can answer it. Measure urself. and am not sure what you mean by **others**? point out what you're referring as other.

Comment: `BlockingCollection` is *much* easier to use than `ConcurrentQueue`. Not only the `GetConsumingEnumerable`, but also non-busy waits are built in. There will likely be *less* synchronization overhead with `BlockingCollection` than if you were to try rolling your own with `ConcurrentQueue`. More importantly, it's very likely that you could introduce race conditions and other hazards if you're trying to use a plain `ConcurrentQueue`. I can't think of a case in which I'd prefer `ConcurrentQueue` over `BlockingCollection`.